# Add rows to a dataframe to get difference of observations by group

Tags: r

I have tidy data like this:

```
df <- tibble(
  country=c(rep("PER",2), rep("COL",2), rep("PER",2)),
  region=rep(c("ama", "anc", "per"), each = 2),
  nivel=c(rep("R", 4),rep("P", 2)),
  sex=rep(c("h", "m"), 3),
  var1=c(2,7,3,5,8,9),
  var2=c(7,6,2,9,3,8))

> df
      country region nivel sex    var1  var2
    1 PER     ama    R     h         2     7
    2 PER     ama    R     m         7     6
    3 COL     anc    R     h         3     2
    4 COL     anc    R     m         5     9
    5 PER     per    P     h         8     3
    6 PER     per    P     m         9     8
```

I need to add **rows** to get the gender gap (h-m) for each var. Rows added should have `sex = "gap"`, and preserve `country`, `nivel` and `sex`. The desired output is:

```
      country region nivel sex    var1  var2
    1 PER     ama    R     h         2     7
    2 PER     ama    R     m         7     6
    3 PER     ama    R     gap      -5     1
    4 COL     anc    R     h         3     2
    5 COL     anc    R     m         5     9
    6 COL     anc    R     gap      -2    -7
    7 PER     per    P     h         8     3
    8 PER     per    P     m         9     8
    9 PER     per    P     gap      -1    -5
```

I need to keep my data long, so most answers (which involve creating additional columns) are not helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(country, region) %>% 
  summarise(sex = "gap", 
            nivel = first(nivel),
            across(var1:var2, ~ -diff(.x))) %>% 
  bind_rows(df) %>% 
  arrange(country, region, desc(sex))
```

output

```r
# A tibble: 9 × 6
# Groups:   country [2]
  country region sex   nivel  var1  var2
  <chr>   <chr>  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 COL     anc    m     R         5     9
2 COL     anc    h     R         3     2
3 COL     anc    gap   R        -2    -7
4 PER     ama    m     R         7     6
5 PER     ama    h     R         2     7
6 PER     ama    gap   R        -5     1
7 PER     per    m     P         9     8
8 PER     per    h     P         8     3
9 PER     per    gap   P        -1    -5
```